# What are the CSS selector names that apply to Gitbook markdown?

Tags: css, pdf, gitbook

I'm trying to figure out how to style my Gitbook book for PDF output. I see a lot of examples that use selectors like .book-body and .page-wrapper, but I can't figure out how those selectors apply to the markdown in my book. In case I'm just asking the wrong questions, what I'm trying to do is make my PDF output from gitbook look nice. I see how to point my book to my pdf.css file, but I have no idea what selector names to use, and can't find any examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CSS selectors for Gitbook markdown correspond to their analogs in HTML: h1, h2, h3, p, ul, ol, blockquote, table, th, td. Note that at least for PDF conversion, nth-child does not work, and as of 2.1.3 of the command-line gitbook, attributes for ul, ol, and blockquote are not applied consistently. But `ul li`, `ol li`, and `blockquote p` have the desired effect. Also, `a` and `img` do not appear to work.

Comment: So you pretty much have to use actual CSS to modify the way the PDF is output? I'm just starting with Gitbook and trying to figure things out.

Comment: @RickHenderson I'm not sure whether CSS is the only way. It's just the only way I know how.